# 4D np.array of dtype 'object' with 3D np.array of dtype 'uint8' as elements

Tags: python, numpy

```
type(imgs):                                                                                                           |
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
--------
imgs.shape                                                                                                           |
(40,) 
-------
imgs[0].shape                                                                                                        |
(3, 512, 512)   
-------
imgs
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)],                                                         |
      dtype=object) 
-------
imgs[0].dtype                                                                                                        |
dtype('uint8')   
-------
imgs.dtype                                                                                                           |
dtype('O')   
-------
imgs[39].dtype                                                                                                       |
dtype('uint8')
```

I want to format imgs to a 4D np.array of dtype('uint8'), not a 1D np.array of dtype('Object') where each element is a 3D np.array of dtype('uint8').

Comment: If all those elements of `imgs` have the same shape, `np.stack(imgs)` should produce the 4d array.